# how transport , network, data link layers functions achieve reliability?

Tags: tcp

we know that transport layer protocols like tcp control the flow and take care of the reliability by slide window and acknowledges ...etc. the data link layer with LLC sub layer has the same functionality for reliable connections also. the first question : is this means that both layers do the same functions twice? or when we use tcp in transport layer there is no need for LLC reliability functions ?how is it working ?

the second question: since IP layer is unreliable when it sends and receives packets, is this means that routers witch are layer 3 devices with no tcp protocol above it depends on LLC sub layer to takes care about the reliability "I mean between two routers" ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need other reliability, in words of disruption, both IP and Physical protocls (such as Ethernet) have CRC and Checksum in order to prevent disruption, but in terms of packet loss, TCP is what's called a stream protocol - it transfers you a stream of bytes, Sequence / Acknowledgment number server that purpose and help you keep track of bytes sent/read by client, if some weird "jump" in those numbers would be made, an ACK message wont be sent by receiving side, and protocol's sender would re-send lost packets hence I don't think that you need some reliability in terms of packet loss as TCP covers that for all downwards layers.... not sure I fully understood your question though, thats when we use TCP

about using pure IP and physical layer protocols, I honestly have no idea how to prevent packet-loss yet disruption is prevented by as mentioned earlier - checksums